# Managing User Connections Outside SignalR Hub in .NET Core: How to Terminate Specific User Connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, real-time

I'm working on a project in .NET Core utilizing SignalR for real-time communication. I need to manage user connections outside of the SignalR Hub. Specifically, I'm trying to terminate specific user connections programmatically from a controller when the user gets removed rather than within the hub itself.

I've tried accessing SignalR connections or hubs directly from a controller but faced limitations in obtaining the specific context of user connections required to call the 'Abort' method and terminate them. Despite exploring SignalR documentation extensively, I haven't discovered a straightforward method for terminating individual user connections outside the hub context.

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using? What client are you using? If you want to manually disconnect a user outside of the hub, you need to wire up a server method inside your client.

Comment: Regarding managing the user connections, you can use a database to store the connection Id and the user Id. SignalR by default, doesn't allow you to query internal groups. You can use concurrent dictionaries to handle it inside of the hub, but if you're scaling out they're useless.

Comment: @GHDevOps I am using the latest version (.NET Core 8)... I'll try to invest some time to read through SignalR source code to try to come up with the best solution possible for this use case.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34481

Comment: @starball kinda

Answer (score 0):

**Implement it in Background Service**

[image]

*1.TimedHostedService.cs*

```
using AspNetCore_SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AspNetCore_SignalR
{
    public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
        private Timer? _timer = null;
        private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly IConnectionManager _connectionManager;


        public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger, IHubContext<MainHub> hubcontext, IConnectionManager connectionManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hubContext = hubcontext;
            _connectionManager = connectionManager;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object? state)
        {
            var allConnections = _connectionManager.GetAllConnections();

            foreach (var userConnections in allConnections)
            {
                string userId = userConnections.Key;
                List<string> connections = userConnections.Value;

                foreach (var connectionId in connections)
                {
                    _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ForceDisconnect");
                }
            }
            //var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);
            //_logger.LogInformation(
            //    "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

*2.MainHub.cs*

```
using AspNetCore_SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace AspNetCore_SignalR.Hubs
{
    public partial class MainHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IConnectionManager _connectionManager;

        public MainHub(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
        {
            _connectionManager = connectionManager;
        }
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            string? userId = Context.GetHttpContext()?.Request.Query["uid"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("User ID is required, can't connect to SignalR service");
                Context.Abort();
                return;
            }

            _connectionManager.AddConnection(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
            Trace.TraceInformation($"{userId} connected");

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            string? userId = Context.GetHttpContext()?.Request.Query["uid"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                _connectionManager.RemoveConnection(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

    }
}
```

*3.IConnectionManager.cs*

```
namespace AspNetCore_SignalR
{
    public interface IConnectionManager
    {
        void AddConnection(string userId, string connectionId);
        void RemoveConnection(string userId, string connectionId);
        List<string> GetConnections(string userId);
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllConnections();
    }
}
```

*4.ConnectionManager.cs*

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace AspNetCore_SignalR
{
    public class ConnectionManager : IConnectionManager
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public void AddConnection(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            _connections.AddOrUpdate(userId, new List<string> { connectionId }, (key, oldValue) => {
                oldValue.Add(connectionId);
                return oldValue;
            });
        }

        public void RemoveConnection(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(userId, out var connections))
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);
                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.TryRemove(userId, out _);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> GetConnections(string userId)
        {
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(userId, out var connections))
            {
                return connections;
            }
            return new List<string>();
        }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllConnections()
        {
            return _connections.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
   builder.Services.AddSignalR();
   builder.Services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();

   builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionManager, ConnectionManager>();
```

---

**Implement it in Controller(if you think it not safe, please refer the updated answer)**

Here is the easiest way to abort the signalr connections. Check the test result first.

[image]

**My Test Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHubContext<MainHub> hubcontext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hubContext = hubcontext;
    }
    public IActionResult abortconnection(string cid)
    {
        // how to abort the signalr connection by connectionId
        _hubContext.Clients.Client(cid).SendAsync("ForceDisconnect");
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**ForceDisconnect event in frontend**

```
connection.on("ForceDisconnect", function () {
    console.log("connection abort");
    connection.stop();
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
});
```

Comment: I don't think I should trust the client side.

Comment: @LouiseYousre You may be a little misunderstood about this, the server sends an instruction to the specified client and executes the ForceDisconnect method, and the specific client that receives the instruction will be disconnected.

Comment: @LouiseYousre Client A cannot disconnect client B through the front-end code, so the client side can be trusted.

Comment: Sadly u didn't get what I meant clearly... what if the client was someone trying to mess with it using let's say postman! he won't just disconnect when he receive it from the server! @jason-pan

Comment: @LouiseYousre Gosh, I'm just giving you an example of where we can implement breaking a specified client outside of the Hub. I'm going to update my answer and use the Background Service to implement it, so you could understand it easily.