# How can i use signal-r in my reactjs app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a reactjs app frontend and c# backend . I have a long running process in the back end , but i need to be able to send messages to the user updating them with what is happening.

Can signal-r do this ? If so how can i simply integrate it in my react app with c# backend and send a message to the front end ?

Comment: Hi Crystal, could you kindly check the answer below, if you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Asp.net core signalr can feet your needs. [Here is the repo for you](https://github.com/Jason446620/react-signalr-sample), and you can find the blog at the end.

And I also implement a requirement about using background service to send message to client side. [You can refer my sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77617710/7687666).