# Abort connections (SignalR) after sign out

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

How do I Abort connections (SignalR) after sign out? How can I change the SignOutAsync method to abort connections?

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
    
        [HttpPost("SignIn")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignInAsync([FromBody] User user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
    
            // User verification by user.Email and user.Password ... 
    
            if (verification == true)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, value: user.Email) };
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
    
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
    
                return Ok();
            }
    
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    
        [HttpDelete("SignOut")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task SignOutAsync(IHubContext<Hubs.TestHub> hubContext)
        {
            if (hubContext != null)
            {
                var nameIdentifier = User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameIdentifier))
                {
                    await hubContext.Clients.User(nameIdentifier).SendAsync("TestHubNotify", $"Sign Out: {nameIdentifier}!");

                    // ???
                    // How do I Abort connections for user (ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?
                    // ???
                }
            }
    
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

The *SignInAsync* method verifies user data (email and password). If the check is successful, the user receives a cookies.

The *SignOutAsync* method sends a message to all user connections. Next, need to somehow abort all user connections. But how to do that? And then the cookies are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalHost` is included in `ASP.NET SignalR`, but has been removed in `ASP.NET Core`, so the server cannot directly call the method to interrupt the connection. We need to call the client's custom `ForceDisconnect` method and use connection.stop(); to interrupt the connection.

*AuthController.cs*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<TestHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly IConnectionManager _connectionManager;

    public AuthController(IHubContext<TestHub> hubContext, IConnectionManager connectionManager)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _connectionManager = connectionManager;
    }

    [HttpDelete("SignOut")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignOutAsync()
    {
        // get userid
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            return BadRequest("User identifier is missing.");
        }

        // get user connections by userid
        var connections = _connectionManager.GetConnections(userId);
        foreach (var connectionId in connections)
        {
            // call frontend method
            await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ForceDisconnect");
        }

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

*Frontend*

```
connection.on("ForceDisconnect", function () {
    console.log("connection abort");
    connection.stop();
});
```

For more details, you can [check my source code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77617710/7687666).

What I need to explain is that this method is very safe. No matter what the scenario is, if a single client executes code through a script in the browser, at most it will only interrupt the connection of this client and will not affect other clients.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. But your solution doesn't make sense. 

1) IConnectionManager - also not used in .NET Core (like GlobalHost) 

2) You don't abort connection on the server side! You send a notification to the client, asking him to disconnect.

3) In my example, I already notify all connections of one user. And I don't need to use IConnectionManager.

Comment: Hi @GranmaSquid3 IConnectionManager is used to manage all the Connections.

Comment: @GranmaSquid3 Please check the  link I provided for all my code and test results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599893/managing-user-connections-outside-signalr-hub-in-net-core-how-to-terminate-spe/77617710#77617710

Comment: I'm not saying your solution won't work. But your solution doesn't abort connections on the server side! You send an alert to clients. And clients must abort the connection on their side.

Comment: My example is identical to yours. I only need to add abort connection code on the client side (frontend).

Comment: @GranmaSquid3 connection.stop will trigger OnDisconnectedAsync, right?

Comment: @GranmaSquid3 So it will abort connections on the server side! You could add a breakpoint to verify it.

Comment: You are terminate the connection on the client side (frontend). How to terminate the connection without using the frontend?

Comment: @GranmaSquid3 There is no any ways can do this, you can raise a github ticket to confirm this